# ML Methods For Modelling Latent Variables

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, machine-learning-model, linear-regression, pytorch

I have some time series predictor variables, $\{\mathbf{X}_t\} = \{\mathbf{X}_0, \ldots, \mathbf{X}_n\}$, and some other time series data $\{\mathbf{Z}_t\} = \{\mathbf{Z}_0, \ldots, \mathbf{Z}_n\}$.

The goal is to estimate some latent variables $\mathbf{Y}$, as functions of $\mathbf{X}_t$. So for e.g. the model's I want to train are:
$$
Y_1 = f_1(\mathbf{X}), \; Y_2 = f_2(\mathbf{X})
$$

However I don't have any true values for what $Y_1$ or $Y_2$ should be. I do have true values for $g(\mathbf{Y}, \mathbf{Z})$. How can I go about setting up my model for training?

I had some ideas using PyTorch, where we can fairly easily set this up in the forward pass (PyTorch Lightning syntax):

```
class MyModule(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.f_1 = ...
    self.f_2 = ...

  def forward(self, X, Z, target):
    y_1_pred = self.f_1(X)
    y_2_pred = self.f_2(X)
    
    g_pred = y_1_pred * Z[:, 0] + y_2_pred * Z[:, 1]
    return g_pred


class MyModel(L.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.my_model = MyModule()

  def forward(self, inputs, target):
    return self.my_model(inputs, target)

  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx)
    inputs_X_Z, target_g = batch
    output_g = self.my_model(inputs_X_Z, target_g)
    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
    loss = criterion(output_g, target_g)
    return loss
```

Are there any other alternative ways/methods? I want to fit several models with low complexity, and deep learning architectures are probably not applicable for my data. I believe that a simple linear regression model could be done with this by setting up my NNs with no hidden layer, but I would like to explore other options too.

Comment: what is $g$?...

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia in practice $g$ is a known equation. I'm trying to model the forces acting on a car. For e.g., let $g$ describe the aerodynamic drag. So $g=0.5\rho C A v^2$. Here, $\rho$ describes air density and $v$ describes relative velocity (both of which changes over time), so $\mathbf{Z}=[\rho, v]$. $A$ is a constant representing frontal area of the car. Lastly, $C$ is a dimensionless coefficient of drag, which corresponds to the $Y$ latent variable, which we are trying to model as a function of $X$ (other predictors such as wind direction for example).